# Bug Histogram Display in C

Tags: c, xcode

i want to do a histogram vertical display of my "election".
My code work just it seems to display wrongly the vote for the 10,11,12,13 value because i think there is 2 numbers  ...
thank you for your time ;)

```
int main() {

    char character ;
    int TAB[12] = {0} ;
    int vote = 0;
    int I;
    printf("Please enter a character:\n"); //character for the display
    scanf(" %c", &character); // character we want to display in the histogram
    printf("Please enter votes\n");
    while(1) {
        scanf("%d", &vote);
        if (vote == -1) {
            break;
        }
        TAB[vote-1]++; //save the vote into the array
    }
        printf("Histogram :\n");
        /* Search for the maximum value */
        int MAX=0;
        for (I=0; I<12; I++)
        {
            if(TAB[I]>TAB[MAX]) MAX=I;

        }

        int maximum = TAB[MAX];  // maximum value

         while (maximum > 0) {

             for (I = 0; I < 12; I++) {
                 if (TAB[I] == maximum) {
                     printf("%c ",character);
                     TAB[I] = (TAB[I] - 1) ;
                 }
                 else {
                     printf("  ");
                 }

             }
             maximum= maximum - 1;

             printf("\n");
         }
    for (I = 0; I < 13; I++) {
        printf("%d ",I+1); // display the number of each candidat
    }
    printf("\n"); // go to the line

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You shouldn't use magic number `12`, use like `#define VOTE_MAX 13`
2. For the range of `vote`, use `if (vote <= 0 || vote > VOTE_MAX)`
3. Format output, `like printf("%2c ", character);`
4. The line `for (I = 0; I < 13; I++) {` should be `for (I = 0; I < 12; I++) {`

The following code could work:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define VOTE_MAX 13

int main() {
  char character;
  int TAB[VOTE_MAX] = {0};
  int vote = 0;
  printf("Please enter a character:\n");  // character for the display
  scanf(" %c", &character);  // character we want to display in the histogram
  printf("Please enter votes\n");
  while (1) {
    scanf("%d", &vote);
    if (vote <= 0 || vote > VOTE_MAX) {
      break;
    }
    TAB[vote - 1]++;  // save the vote into the array
  }
  printf("Histogram :\n");
  /* Search for the maximum value */
  int MAX = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < VOTE_MAX; ++i) {
    if (TAB[i] > TAB[MAX]) MAX = i;
  }

  int maximum = TAB[MAX];  // maximum value

  while (maximum > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < VOTE_MAX; ++i) {
      if (TAB[i] == maximum) {
        printf("%2c ", character);
        --TAB[i];
      } else {
        printf("%2c ", ' ');
      }
    }
    --maximum;

    printf("\n");
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < VOTE_MAX; ++i) {
    printf("%2d ", i + 1);  // display the number of each candidat
  }
  printf("\n");  // go to the line

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an extra space for the cases where `I` is 10 or higher.

Like:

```
         for (I = 0; I < 12; I++) {
             if (TAB[I] == maximum) {
                 printf("%c ",character);
                 TAB[I] = (TAB[I] - 1) ;
             }
             else {
                 printf("  ");
             }

             if (I >= 9) printf(" ");  // Add extra space for 10, 11 and 12

         }
```

BTW: your input method should be improved. Currently the user can enter values that will make your write outside the array. At least do something like:

```
while(1) {
    if (scanf("%d", &vote) != 1) break;  // Catch illegal input
    if (vote <= 0 || vote >= 13) {  // Only allow vote to be 1, 2, …, 10, 11, 12
        break;
    }
    TAB[vote-1]++; //save the vote into the array
}
```